# exception>: TypeError undefined is not a function

Tags: backbone.js

```
<script id="index-recipe" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var MyNamespace = { Views: {}};

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var template = Handlebars.compile($("#entry-template").html());
            var templateRecipe = Handlebars.compile($("#index-recipe").html());

            var recipes = [name = "Chicken Chilly", name = "Chicken Manchurian"];

            MyNamespace.MyTagView = Backbone.View.extend({
                template: templateRecipe,
                initialize: function () {
                    this.render();
                },
                render: function () {
                    this.$el.html(this.template(this));
                    var ViewRecipes = new MyNamespace.Recipes({ collection: recipes });
                    this.$el.append(ViewRecipes.render().el);
                    return this;
                }

            });


            MyNamespace.Recipes = Backbone.View.extend({
                render: function () {
                    this.collection.forEach(function (recipe) {
                        var ViewRecipe = new Backbone.Recipe({ model: recipe });
                        this.$el.append(ViewRecipe.render().el);
                    }, this)
                    return this;
                }
            });

            MyNamespace.Recipe = Backbone.View.extend({
                render: function () {
                    this.$el.text("I am Recipe");
                    return this;
                }
            });

            var View = new MyNamespace.MyTagView();
            $("#content").html(View.el);
        });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** Finally got it working.  (See link below.)

1. `Recipe` should be the one that owns the "entry-template".  It should render using that template and its model.
2. Pass an actual `Backbone.Model` instance to the `Recipe` view, and a `Backbone.Collection` instance to the `Recipes` view.

---

There is a typo `Backbone.Recipe`, which of course doesn't exist.

```
var ViewRecipe = new MyNamespace.Recipe({ model: recipe });
```

Also, in what you posted there's no template definition for "#entry-template".

[Here's a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/BUJr5/26/)